# React Router | URL parameter as variable *without* useParams?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, reach-router

I'm currently working on this page of the Apollo Odyssey tutorial: https://www.apollographql.com/tutorials/lift-off-part3/the-usequery-hook---with-variables

I came to an interesting realization here: the `Track` component is receiving the `trackId` prop from the URL parameters, *without* the `useParams` hook. I've never heard of that being possible, and I cannot quite conceptualize *how* this program is doing it. I'll provide the two relevant file's codes below, but the entire repo can be found here: https://github.com/apollographql/odyssey-lift-off-part3

How is this occurring? Is this a feature of React Router that I'm unaware of?

```
// track.js
import React from "react";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { Layout, QueryResult } from "../components";
import TrackDetail from "../components/track-detail";

export const GET_TRACK = gql`
  query getTrack($trackId: ID!) {
    track(id: $trackId) {
      id
      title
      author {
        id
        name
        photo
      }
      thumbnail
      length
      modulesCount
      numberOfViews
      modules {
        id
        title
        length
      }
      description
    }
  }
`;

const Track = ({ trackId }) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_TRACK, {
    variables: { trackId },
  });

  return (
    <Layout>
      <QueryResult error={error} loading={loading} data={data}>
        <TrackDetail track={data?.track} />
      </QueryResult>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Track;
```

```
// index.js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Router } from '@reach/router';
/** importing our pages */
import Tracks from './tracks';
import Track from './track';

export default function Pages() {
  return (
    <Router primary={false} component={Fragment}>
      <Tracks path="/" />
      <Track path="/track/:trackId" />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are confusing 2 libraries. Reach router and react router. They only merged in React router version v6 and reach router v2, while the code you post still uses '^1.3.4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, silly me. This project uses `Reach Router`, not `React Router`. Easy mistake.